# Trying to use gsdll32.dll via Ghostscript.NET on Azure web apps fails (worked before)

Tags: c#, azure

I'm trying to use the dll version of ghost script in an azure web app. It has worked before, but now I start getting these errors when using Ghostscript.

```
An error occured when call to 'gsapi_new_instance' is made: -100
```

I'm using Ghostscript.NET for working with Ghostscript.

From reading other posts here, it could be because of missing permissions. But I'm not sure which permissions I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I have created a test demo using Ghostscript.NET with "gsdll32.dll" and published the application to azure. It works well(I don't change any setting).

As you said, it worked well before. I think this error is not related with your permissions. I suggest you could follow below step to troubleshoot the application.

1.Use [remote debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio) to check the gsdll32.dll path is right in your application code

2.Create a new app web app and published the application to it and test again.

More details about my test codes, you could refer to below:

```
        GhostscriptVersionInfo gvi = new GhostscriptVersionInfo(Server.MapPath("~/dll/gsdll32.dll"));

        GhostscriptProcessor proc = new GhostscriptProcessor(gvi);
        string inputFile = Server.MapPath("~/File/Test Document.pdf"); 
        string outputFile = Server.MapPath("~/File/page-%03d.png");

        int pageFrom = 1;
        int pageTo = 2;

        List<string> switches = new List<string>();
        switches.Add("-empty");
        switches.Add("-dSAFER");
        switches.Add("-dBATCH");
        switches.Add("-dNOPAUSE");
        switches.Add("-dNOPROMPT");
        switches.Add("-dFirstPage=" + pageFrom.ToString());
        switches.Add("-dLastPage=" + pageTo.ToString());
        switches.Add("-sDEVICE=png16m");
        switches.Add("-r96");
        switches.Add("-dTextAlphaBits=4");
        switches.Add("-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4");
        switches.Add(@"-sOutputFile=" + outputFile);
        switches.Add(@"-f");
        switches.Add(inputFile);

        proc.Process(switches.ToArray());
```

Result:

[image]